# Why is C# PInvoke with serial port overlapped I/O sometimes giving me all zeros

Tags: c#, serial-port, pinvoke, overlapped-io

I am making a simple RS-232 test app in C#. After having problems with .NET `SerialPort`, I decided to call Win32 APIs directly.

I am using overlapped I/O. It is working 70% of the time, and the other time the inbound data isn't written to the buffer.

My test app opens the COM port this way:

```
_handle = CreateFile(
    @"\\.\COM1",
    FileAccess.ReadWrite,
    FileShare.None,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    FileMode.Open,
    EFileAttributes.Overlapped,
    IntPtr.Zero
    );
```

Note the overlapped flag.

Then the app sets COM parameters. `GetCommState`, set baud, 0 stop bit, no parity, disable all flow control and RTS and DTR (all of this except baud is default anyway), then `SetCommState`.

Next the app sets timeout via `SetCommTimeouts`, and `ReadIntervalTimeout` is 1ms, all others are zero.

And then the app cycles DTR via `EscapeCommFunction` to `CLRDTR`, and a 200ms sleep, and `EscapeCommFunction` to  `SETDTR`.

All of this sets up the COM port well. When connected to a shell, I/O works perfectly, because messages are short. When messages have any significant length, say 30 bytes at once, I am encountering problems with overlapped I/O response on `ReadFile`.

My rx code is below.

**Problem** The data is coming in properly, the overlapped operation completes as expected, the length from the overlapped operation is always correct, but `ioBuffer` 30% of the time isn't filled and remains all zeros.

Seems to be pinvoke. While I had problems using .NET `SerialPort`, losing data like this wasn't an issue.

Anyone spot something wrong?

```
DataReceivedArgs args = new DataReceivedArgs();
ManualResetEvent completionEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
NativeOverlapped nol = new NativeOverlapped();
nol.EventHandle = completionEvent.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
int dontCare = 0;

try
{
    for (; ; )
    {
        completionEvent.Reset();
        uint bytesRead = 0;

        nol.InternalHigh = IntPtr.Zero;
        nol.InternalLow = IntPtr.Zero;
        nol.OffsetHigh = 0;
        nol.OffsetLow = 0;

        byte[] ioBuffer = new byte[1024];

        if (!ReadFile(_handle.DangerousGetHandle(), ioBuffer, ioBuffer.Length, out dontCare, ref nol))
        {
            int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (lastError != OperationInProgress)
            {
                if (lastError != ErrorInvalidHandle)
                {
                    Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(lastError);
                    MessageBox.Show("ReadFile failed. Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
                break;
            }

            completionEvent.WaitOne();
            // Have tried sleeping here to see if there is timing involved, no luck

            if (!GetOverlappedResult(_handle.DangerousGetHandle(), ref nol, out bytesRead, true))
            {
                bytesRead = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IOException();
        }

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            byte[] sizedBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
            Array.Copy(ioBuffer, 0, sizedBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            args.Data = sizedBuffer;
            DataReceived?.Invoke(this, args);
        }
    }
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
}
```

And pinvoke signature

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ReadFile(
    IntPtr hFile, 
    [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, 
    int nNumberOfBytesToRead, 
    [Out] out int lpNumberOfBytesRead,
    ref NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped
    );
```

Comment: Why not solve the problem you have with the SerialPort class? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport

Comment: SerialPort has several design problems. You can search the web to find out what they are. I hit several well known problems with unreliable notifications and UI thread deadlocks with a very simple use case.

Answer (score 1):

The outbound data of `ReadFile` is possibly getting moved by the GC.

PInvoke requires OUT parameters used by overlapped I/O to be pinned.

Fixed code:

```
DataReceivedArgs args = new DataReceivedArgs();
ManualResetEvent completionEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
byte[] ioBuffer = new byte[1024];
NativeOverlapped nol = new NativeOverlapped
{
    EventHandle = completionEvent.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle()
};

try
{
    for (; ; )
    {
        completionEvent.Reset();
        uint bytesRead = 0;

        GCHandle pin = GCHandle.Alloc(ioBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        try
        {
            if (!ReadFile(_handle.DangerousGetHandle(), ioBuffer, ioBuffer.Length, out int dontCare, ref nol))
            {
                int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (lastError != OperationInProgress)
                {
                    if (lastError != ErrorInvalidHandle)
                    {
                        Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(lastError);
                        MessageBox.Show("ReadFile failed. Error: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                completionEvent.WaitOne();

                if (!GetOverlappedResult(_handle.DangerousGetHandle(), ref nol, out bytesRead, true))
                {
                    bytesRead = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IOException();
            }

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                byte[] sizedBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
                Array.Copy(ioBuffer, 0, sizedBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                args.Data = sizedBuffer;
                DataReceived?.Invoke(this, args);
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            pin.Free();
        }
    }
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
}

completionEvent.Dispose();
```

Comment: Do you have a working example of the code? I am working on something similar, it would really help me to have something to refer to

Comment: I don't have it handy. All that's missing is code that launches this as a worker thread after opening the port. A member variable, DataReceived, is a standard event. `delegate void DataReceivedDelegate(object sender, DataReceivedArgs args); event DataReceivedDelegate DataReceived;` and DataRecievedArgs is a simple wrapper of EventArgs (`class DataReceivedArgs : EventArgs`...). WriteFile for sending was straight forward.

Comment: I don't understand why `ioBuffer` is being garbage collected when it's still being reference  in the third line `byte[] ioBuffer = new byte[1024];`.

Comment: Rick - referenced allocations can move around in memory by the GC when they are unpinned.